# Symfony2 and Ubuntu 11.10 permission folder and file

Tags: symfony, netbeans-7, ubuntu-11.10

When i open some files(Symfony2.0) with netbeans, this say me:Cannot Lock read Only
i must click right mouse and set every folder the permission to "read and write"
this is big problem because i must set every folder and file.....
how i can fix this my problem permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add write permissions to the whole folder/subfolders and files.
For example:

> chmod -R u+w foldername
>
> -R is to do it for sub-folders and all files (recursive)
>
> u - is for the owner (your user)
>
> +w - is to add write permissions

Perhaps you created symfony2 files using root where netbeans uses user permissions which is currently logged in. Make sure your files/folders belong to user not to the root

Answer (score 0):

If your user is different from the user the server is running as (apache, httpd, www-data for instance), then you must either add yourself to the server group and chmod all the files so group permissions are set to read and write, or chown all the files to you (chown -R user:user) and add your server user to your group.

Also, dont forget to set proper permissions on the cache/ and log/ folders
(they must be writable by the command line user when you do a cache:clear and also writable by the server user)

For more info you can check the "setting up permissions" paragraph on the Installing Symfony Chapter of the Symfony book here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: how i can add my user into group?

Comment: To add a user to a group (as a secondary group) use:

usermod -G group username